# How to install ag-Grid enterprise properly?

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

i have tested some components with **ag-Grid community edition** but it has limited supportability, such as to add **set filters** using `SetFilterModule`, so the filter boxes would appear under the column header name, cannot be done with community version, therefore i have uninstalled the community version and installed the enterprise version using npm command

```
npm i ag-grid-enterprise
```

after installing `package.json` shows dependencies and **node_modules** folder shows Enterprise modules.

But when i tried to import `AgGridModule` from the import statement in the `app.module.ts`  it did not show `AgGridModule` on the drop down. As shown on the image below, it had only three options `LicenseManager, SetFilter, VirtualList`. so, It had given me the impression that it required a license. But according to **agGrid** website i can use the full enterprise version of the grid without a license and the only barriers it will add are water marks and the console error message.

https://www.ag-grid.com/license-pricing.php

But in order to at least see those console messages i have to install it properly. So i believe that i have not installed the **agGrid** properly yet.

Therefore can anyone provide me on the steps on how to install the **agGrid enterprise version** and run it **without** a license key ( with watermark and console error messages )?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To add `ag-grid-enterprise` to your application, you must also have `ag-grid-community` also installed. The reason for this can be found [here in the documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-packages/).

Since you are using Angular, you also need to add the framework support by adding `ag-grid-angular` to your app.
In your modules file you must import the `AgGridModule` from `ag-grid-angular`:

```
import { AgGridModule } from 'ag-grid-angular';
```

Once these 3 packages are installed, you can enable enterprise features in your app by adding the following line to your component file:

```
import "ag-grid-enterprise";
```

You can find documentation for all of this in the ag-grid [angular getting started guide](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-grid/).

I've created a [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-angular-hello-world-y9k3ar?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) which has `ag-grid-enterprise` working on Angular.

Comment: i am using version 22 of ag-grid. has something changed ? maybe I dont need community in version 22.

Comment: @MindRoasterMir Yes, there is now two methods of adding ag-grid into your application. 

The first method is the package method, which is using the following NPM packages: ag-grid-enterprise, ag-grid-community, ag-grid-angular etc.

The second method is the modules method which uses the NPM packages @ag-grid-enterprise/XXX, @ag-grid-community/XXX

Have a read of the documentation, which shoud clarify which one you are using, and how to add enterprise features to your app: https://www.ag-grid.com/documentation/javascript/packages-modules/

Comment: Thanks for your message. I was trying to get excel data exported and this is how i managed to do it. https://itlog.mscod.net/index.php?threads/how-to-use-ag-grid-enterprise-to-export-table-data-to-excel-in-angular.39/

Comment: AG Grid documentation on this is horrible. Install instructions for enterprise show only the module method @ag-grid-enterprise/all-modules, but no mention of Angular. It says framework specific instructions are in the getting started docs, but when you look there, it only documents installing ag-grid-community and ag-grid-angular. ag-grid-angular appears to depend on ag-grid-community only. Have yet to find any docs, or to get it working, using @ag-grid-enterprise/all-modules with Angular.

Answer (score 1):

With almost no help from the AG Grid documentation, I finally ran across this for the module method of installation with Angular.

```
npm install @ag-grid-enterprise/all-modules
npm install @ag-grid-community/angular
```

(If you want to install only certain modules, instead of `all-modules`, install only the ones you want.)

If moving from the community package install, be sure to uninstall packages `ag-grid-community` and `ag-grid-angular`, and replace all of your imports to use the new modules instead of the old packages.

For styles in your `styles.scss`:

```
@import "../node_modules/@ag-grid-community/core/dist/styles/ag-grid.css";
@import "../node_modules/@ag-grid-community/core/dist/styles/ag-theme-<whatever-theme-you-want>.css";
```

*Edit:*

I did finally find reference to `@ag-grid-community/angular` in their docs, *Modules Overview* page, which also outlines all of the modules to install for specific features, both community and enterprise, instead of installing `@ag-grid-enterprise/all-modules`: https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/modules/

Answer (score 0):

After messing around with trying to get Enterprise installed correctly, I finally found that I could do this:

```
import {LicenseManager} from "ag-grid-enterprise";
LicenseManager.setLicenseKey("KEY HERE");
```

(Without the **@** and no **/core**)

And that solved my issues.

Comment: I've suggested to Ag Grid team to include these details on https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/npm/ & https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/licensing/