# Is it possible to add a second ag-grid table inside the Tool Panel Component of ag-grid

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

Here is the codesanbox link I tried. You can try replacing the value of "toolPanel" in index.tsx file (currently set to CustomStatsToolPanel) with "StaticTable" or "AGTable" to see the effects. NO matter what the AGGrid table is not loading inside it.

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/ag-grid-packages-forked-5nfqm7

Comment: custom tool panel need Enterprises version of ag grid setup correctly ? Did you made sure that you have the enterprises product key setup correctly ? here is the link https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/component-tool-panel/#implementing-a-tool-panel-component

Comment: here is the link to check if did setup the enterprises version correctly - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64965718/how-to-install-ag-grid-enterprise-properly